# Compute the vector $v$ if the coordinate vector $[v]_{s}$ is given with respect to each ordered basis $S$ for $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, so this is a practice question in my book:

$V$ is $M_{22}$

$S=$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-2\\
0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&3\\
0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\
1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}

and $[v]_{s}=$

\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}

The answer is 
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1\\
2&1\\
\end{bmatrix}

But I can't figure out how they get to that. I know it is supposed to be

$[v]_{s}=$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
a_{3}\\
a_{4}\\
\end{bmatrix}

But I cant figure how they get to it. The 2x2 matrix syntax is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I had a friend explain it to me!

Here is the answer:

Since $[v]_{s}=$

\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
a_{3}\\
a_{4}\\
\end{bmatrix}

you just multiply $a_{1}* v_{1} + a_{2}*v_{2} + a_{3}* v_{3}+a_{4}* v_{4}$ to get your answer.

Very simple really.